# Exam Class, Keep Question and Mutiple Choice Answers on the Same Page?

Tags: formatting, page-breaking, multicol, exam

I've seen that there have been attempts to answer this question before. I am unsatisfied with the answers, as they do not meet the standards that I require. Many of the threads addressing this topic also seem outdated. Is there a way to keep a question and its multiple-choice answers on the same page?

[image]

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,12pt,addpoints]{exam}%
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

%
% packages
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[overload]{exam-randomizechoices}
\usepackage{multicol}

%
% seed for exam-randomizerchoices
\setrandomizerseed{314}

\begin{document}

\begin{questions}

    \question \lipsum[1]
    \begin{multicols}{2}
        \begin{choices}
        \CorrectChoice 1
        \choice 2
        \choice 3
        \choice 4
    \end{choices}
    \end{multicols}
    
    \question \lipsum[1]
    \begin{multicols}{2}
        \begin{choices}
        \CorrectChoice 1
        \choice 2
        \choice 3
        \choice 4
    \end{choices}
    \end{multicols}
    
    \question \lipsum[1]
    \begin{multicols}{2}
        \begin{choices}
        \CorrectChoice 1
        \choice 2
        \choice 3
        \choice 4
    \end{choices}
    \end{multicols}
    
    \question \lipsum[1]
    \begin{multicols}{2}
        \begin{choices}
        \CorrectChoice 1
        \choice 2
        \choice 3
        \choice 4
    \end{choices}
    \end{multicols}
    
\end{questions}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I think the best you can do are: 
1. use one single line for the answers using `oneparchoices` if your answers are short enough to fit all of them in one line,
2. making your footer as small as possible and, 
3. if these are not satisfying, then use `pagebreak` or `newpage` commands.

Comment: Encapsulate the question and choices between `\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}` and  `\end{minipage}`. They will say together or go both to the next page.

Comment: @SimonDispa I think I got it working. I was having trouble getting it to work in a more complex project. However, it gets rid of the spacing between questions. I can add space manually or is there a more natural way?